# Loop variables in Vue.js similar to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

I my `vue.js` application I want to know the last repeated element in a `v-for` directive. I know there is something similar in `angularjs` with the `$last` loop variable in its [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj">
  <span ng-if="$last">Shows if it is the last loop element</span>
</div>
```

Is there any equivalent in `vue.js` which I am not aware of or do I have to implement some own logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me :)

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <span  v-if="index === (items.length-1)">This is the last loop element</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also put the logic in a computed property :

```
  <div v-for="(value, key) in myObj">
    <span v-if="key === last">This is the last loop element : {{ value }}</span>
  </div>

  //...
  computed: {
    last() {
      let keys = Object.keys(this.myObj)
      return keys.slice(-1)[0]
    }
  }
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/ej6jhq1p/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent for this in Vue, no.

Comment: Vue's come a long way in two years :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead, check for index if it is last

```
  <div v-for="(value, key, index) in myObj">
     <div v-if="index === Object.keys(myObj).length-1"> my content</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this

```
<div v-repeat="myObj">
 <span v-if="$index === (myObj.length-1)">Shows if it is the last loop element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Objects do not have a length property, use `Object.keys(myObj).length`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nisha answer I have been doing this:

```
<template v-for="(obj, index) in originalData">
    <template v-if="index == 0 || (index >= 1 && obj.valueA !== originalData[index - 1].valueA)">
        {{ obj.valueA }}
    </template>
</template>
```

I want the loop to always happen the first time, but to conditionally check a value for every loop afterwards. I am using `<template>` tags to avoid outputting unnecessary markup. In my example originalData is an array of objects.